# Thermostat to DB, OOP Design

Tags: java, oop, uml

I am attempting my first Java project (just started learning it/OOP). I have built a thermostat circuit that I can get the temperature from using a driver, and am now in the process of designing a Java program that interfaces with the thermostat and inserts the data into a mysql DB.

I'm attempting to do this properly, and so have come up with a basic UML diagram of my classes/objects and how they interact.

I plan on using a database interface class which will extend a database connection class. This database interface will insert into the DB, and the database connection constructor will create the database connection.

I will also have a thermostat class which interfaces with the thermostat itself, it will have 2 private variables, temperature and humidity. It will have the method update temp, which will update the private variables. The get temp method will be provide the interface to these private variables.

Finally the control class is composed of the thermostat and database interface classes, and will call the methods of both classes to get the temp/humidity data into the database.

UML diagram:

[image: uml diagram]

Do you have any thoughts? I don't know how good this design is. Is the controller interacting with the other classes in the correct way?

Thank you for your time.

X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for someone that just "just started learning it/OOP" it look pretty good!

One thing that jumps out as me: It works, but seems idiomatically wrong (we don't usually do it that way) is having your DAO (data access object, "Database Interface") *extend* the class that creates the connection.   Instead is should *use* this class-- or better, the result of this class, a connection.

Why? As you write more DAO classes (in this project, or others) you'll probably find that these are two separate concerns:

(1) code that deals with the temp/humidity table and related SQL and, temperature specific logic and exceptions.

(2) code that is responsible for connecting to a database and creating connection objects.

If you have a databaseInterface.setConnection(Connection c) method, you'll find that your databaseInterface class is more reusable.  You can set connections from various sources, create multiple instances with different connections, inject *mock* connections in your test cases, etc.

These are ideas that I have learned over years and usually apply to projects with tens to hundreds of data access classes.  Its not a terribly significant in a small project, but is a possible improvement nonetheless.

EDIT: Possible Controller constructor:

```
// My hardware interface
private Thermostat thermostat;

// My temperature DB tables interface
private TemperatureDAO temperatureDAO;

public Controller() {
    thermostat = new Thermostat();
    temperatureDAO = new TemperatureDAO();     
    // As the controller, I get to decide what connection the application uses.
    temperatureDAO.setConnection(new ConnectionProvider().getConnection());
}
```

In this code the controller is dictating which DB connection is used, not each individual DAO.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So regarding the database interface, are you suggesting that the db interface should be composed of a database connection object, instead of the inheritance?

Comment: Yes, composition over inheritance in this case.

Comment: Thanks again, did you have any thoughts on the controller class? I wasn't really sure on how I should tie everything together.

Comment: The existence of the controller is a good design I think.  In large applications the way people generally wire things up (tie everything together) these days is using Spring (or some other dependency injection framework). But, you probably don't want to use that in this simple project.

Perhaps start simple, in the controller constructor.... let me edit the answer above so that it is formatted....

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, it makes more sense with your example. I guess the only tricky part is ensuring that the Thermostat DAO set connection works in a way that supports multiple connection providers.

Comment: Well, there is an interface in java: java.sql.Connection.   That is *THE* interface returned by the JDBC driver for ALL databases (MySQL, Oracle, anything).  So as long as your setter takes that, you should be ok.

Comment: Brilliant, I will be sure to utilize the java.sql.Connection. Thanks again.

Comment: This may be beyond the scope of your project but....In the example above I'm injecting a connection into the DAO.  The more common approach I guess is to inject an implementation of javax.sql.DataSource, which has a getConnection() method.  The reason for this is that people usually don't write their own connection provider (or DataSource) but instead use one provided by their framework/application-server, which delegates to a pool of connections.... but maybe that is too much information for now :-)

Comment: Regarding my UML diagram, it seems wrong that im duplicating variables and methods in my controller class and other classes, or is this okay?

Comment: The DAO, and connection injection does sort of make sense, buts its probably something I need to read into a bit more :). Thanks for the information.

Comment: Well I did wonder why "Thermostat" has to have them as local fields, instead of reading/setting the values directly on the hardware-- there are **possible** reasons.... for example, if you needed to cache in the Thermostat class.  Presumably they need to be in the controller because from there you display them, or print them, or otherwise access them periodically.  But yeah, eliminate the duplicates if you can.

Comment: Okay, so wherever possible remove the duplication. I think the controller class could be reduced to a single method, which reads using the controller object method and then inserts using the database interface object method, e.g. a readAndInsertTemp/Humid method, although I'm not sure whether in the UML diagram, you would represent the two methods this "master" method utilizes.